# Что значит это условие? if($data=mysql_fetch_row($res)) { }

Tags: условия, mysql

Не могу понять, что дословно значит это условие:

```
if($data=mysql_fetch_row($res))
{
}
```

Это условие - часть проверки на наличие id.

В переменной `$res` находится массив с результатом `mysql_query`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызываем метод mysql_fetch_row, который возвращает очередную строку результата, и сохраняем в переменную data. Если то, что сохранили в data, не равно FALSE (то есть больше записей нет), то условие истинно.

Это можно развернуто переписать так:

```
$data=mysql_fetch_row($res);
if($data) { }
```

В Вашем случае, видимо, проверяется наличие всего одной записи.

Такой формат записи достаточно популярный, он позволяет сэкономить одну, а порой и две строки, хотя читаемость обычно сильно страдает.

Comment: да. это проверка на наличие id.
весь код выглядит так. $res=mysql_query('select * FROM '.$carBrand.' where id='.(int)$_GET['id']);
if($data=mysql_fetch_row($res))
{
}else{
      header ("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
      header('Location:./404.php');
      exit(); 
}

Но я не могу понять. Получается так если строки с таким id существуют значит выполняем код дальше. если нет значит 404 ошибка.

А если нужно проверить несколько параметров? например id, marka, model? как тогда записать этот код?

Comment: если нужно проверить несколько параметров, то нужно подумать, как именно нужно проверять, составить запрос и проверить. К примеру, если нужно проверить, что есть запись для данной модели и марки (то есть, в одной строке), то нужно просто переписать запрос

    select * FROM '.$carBrand.' where model='.$_GET['model'].' and marka = '.$_GET['marka']

правда вставлять get параметры прямо в запрос - это очень плохая затея - для одного теста - нормально, для всего остального - грусть-печалька.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите оф. документацию, там четко сказано, что это за функция и что она возвращает
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-fetch-row.php
Конкретно это условие проверяет, остались ли еще данные для выборки из БД.

Comment: @Антон Лакотко, ну, все-таки нет. Эта функция подтягивает следующий результат, и, если его нет, тогда возвращает false. То есть это условие проверяет, вытянула ли функция какие-нибудь данные.

Comment: @Etki да, вы правы. Не правильно выразил свои мысли, даже ошибочно.